Load balance TCP stream traffic based on delimiter
I am looking for clarification if either Nginx or HAProxy are capable of load balancing TCP stream content based on some delimiters in the stream. The TCP connection is long-lived and is being used for MLLP protocol. In short the MLLP protocol is:
<VT>Message<FS><CR>[time gap]
<VT>Message<FS><CR>…

Messages can come as continuous stream or with variable time gap between them.
The goal is to split the stream based on the predefined delimiters and make a load balancing decision based on the “message” in the envelope. Bonus points for keeping the implementation as native as possible to either of the products.
I have tried OpenResty/lua and HAProxy’s SPOE. Seems that both do support load balancing based on stream’s content but only at the point of the initial connection, any traffic afterwards goes through an established connections.
I would appreciate any insight. Thank you!

Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it. And Welcome.
